# Vertical button bar layout using miglayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm wondering about the "best" way to achieve a relatively usual layout with mig layout.
I have large components (say, JLists in this case), and buttons between the two large components. So I want a vertical button stack, with a gap at the bottom. I have done it a couple of time, but

1. there seems to be a lot of ways to achieve this result ;
2. each time, I proceeded by trial and errors, and I feel I must miss something.
3. in any case, as this is a rather usual problem, it would be nice to have a sample somewhere, and stackOverflow seems to be used as the MigLayout wiki.

So, I want to achieve this presentation with miglayout :

```
+---------------+  +----+  +----------------------+
|  list 1       |  | bt1|  |  list2               |
|               |  +----+  |                      |
|               |  +----+  |                      |
|               |  | bt2|  |                      |
|               |  +----+  |                      |
|               |  +----+  |                      |
|               |  | bt3|  |                      |
|               |  +----+  |                      |
|               |          |                      |
|               |          |                      |
+---------------+          +----------------------+
```

Currently, I do :

```
add(new JScrollPane(jlist1),"grow, pushy");
add(button1,"flowy, aligny top, split 3");
add(button2, "");
add(button3, "");
add(new JScrollPane(jlist2), "grow, pushy");
```

Are there better ways to do it? Is it worthwhile to avoid creating a panel for putting the buttons in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just put the buttons in their own panel.  That simplifies the layout and similar components tend to get modified together so it is good to have them in their separate function or class.

Whenever possible I try to use a tree-like structure of containers rather than have a complicated layout that includes all the components.  It makes it harder to read and rearrange things when everything depends on the layout of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this layout: You can do this fairly simple with `MigLayout`, without the need for an additional `JPanel` as a button container:

```
/**
 * Simple assign panel layout.
 */
public class AssignView extends JPanel {
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane_1;
    private JList<Object> list;
    private JList<Object> list_1;

    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private JButton btnNewButton_1;
    private JButton btnNewButton_2;
    private JButton btnNewButton_3;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public AssignView() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][][grow]", "[grow,top]"));
        add(getScrollPane(), "cell 0 0,grow");
        add(getBtnNewButton(), "flowy,cell 1 0");
        add(getScrollPane_1(), "cell 2 0,grow");
        add(getBtnNewButton_2(), "cell 1 0");
        add(getBtnNewButton_1(), "cell 1 0");
        add(getBtnNewButton_3(), "cell 1 0");
    }

    private JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
        if (scrollPane == null) {
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(getList());
        }
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JButton getBtnNewButton() {
        if (btnNewButton == null) {
            btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        }
        return btnNewButton;
    }

    private JScrollPane getScrollPane_1() {
        if (scrollPane_1 == null) {
            scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane_1.setViewportView(getList_1());
        }
        return scrollPane_1;
    }

    private JButton getBtnNewButton_1() {
        if (btnNewButton_1 == null) {
            btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
        }
        return btnNewButton_1;
    }

    private JButton getBtnNewButton_2() {
        if (btnNewButton_2 == null) {
            btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        }
        return btnNewButton_2;
    }

    private JList<Object> getList() {
        if (list == null) {
            list = new JList<>();
        }
        return list;
    }

    private JList<Object> getList_1() {
        if (list_1 == null) {
            list_1 = new JList<>();
        }
        return list_1;
    }

    private JButton getBtnNewButton_3() {
        if (btnNewButton_3 == null) {
            btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("New button");
        }
        return btnNewButton_3;
    }
}
```

[image]